# vs codeとmacに入れたvagrantでうまく環境を構築するには？

Tags: python, python3, vagrant, vscode

今までsublime textを使用してプログラムを書いてました。

mac os high sierra
ubuntu 14.04

vagrantで起動しているlinuxの中にインストールしたpython3でデバックしていました。

今回、macのテキストエディタをvs codeに変えようと思ってインストールしたのですが以下の警告文が出てきます。

> The macOS system install of Python is not recommended, some
>   functionality in the extension will be limited. Install another
>   version of Python for the best experience.

これはデバックに使うpythonにMacにインストールされたものを使うのはやめましょうという事だと思います。
多分、macに入っているpythonが古い(2.7系)からだと思います。

なるべくMacのシステムをいじりたくはないのでvagrantのubuntu14.04にインストールしたpython3をvs codeのデバックに当てたいのですが、そのような事が可能なのでしょうか

**質問**
vagrantでubuntuを起動した状態でmacから仮想環境内のpythonを使用できるのかという事です。
もしくはこの警告文が出ないようにしてデバック機能なしでsublime textのように使用したいです。

詳しい方教えて頂けると幸いです。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: Python3.xはゲスト環境(Ubuntu)、エディタのVS Codeはホスト環境(macOS)で使いたい、ということでしょうか。

Comment: はいそうです！もしこの状態でubuntu側のpythonを使ってvs code内でコードを実行できたりするといちいちubuntu側のターミナルで実行しなくて済むと考えているのですが、可能でしょうか？

Comment: 個々のツールとか版数とか違いますが、この辺が参考になるのでは？ [【VSCode】Docker上で動くPythonに接続してリモートデバッグする方法](https://blog.stedplay.com/how-to-remote-debug-python-on-docker-in-vscode/), [VS CodeでDockerのPython環境でリモート開発](https://chigusa-web.com/vs-code%E3%81%A7docker%E3%81%AEpython%E7%92%B0%E5%A2%83%E3%81%A7%E3%83%AA%E3%83%A2%E3%83%BC%E3%83%88%E9%96%8B%E7%99%BA/), [VSCodeでのPythonのデバッグと、Dockerコンテナ環境に接続してリモートデバッグする方法](https://qiita.com/Ryuichirou/items/6327ab5012ca1729d72f), [Python Docker Remote Debugging VS Code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50778583/9014308)